# What's the use case of a protected method in a final class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, awt, final

Consider this code from the official [OpenJDK source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/awt/font/TextLayout.java) of `java.awt.font.TextLayout`:

```
public final class TextLayout {

    /* ... */

    protected void handleJustify(float justificationWidth) {
      // never called
    }
}
```

What's the use case here and why might it make sense to write code like that in general?

Comment: This particular method seems to be *entirely* useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`protected` members can still be accessed by code from the same package. My guess is that the class used to be non-final in some earlier (perhaps not even public) version, was then made final, and the protected method kept as such because there might be code in the same package that uses it (and not changed to package private simply because nobody saw a benefit from doing so).

Comment: @Michael, Does the existence of a protected method suggests that TextLayout was *previously* actually intended to be sub-classed?

Comment: @Pacerier: yes, that's the only reason to use protected.

Answer (score 5):

Protected is (see [access levels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)):

- For extending classes, regardless of package.
- All classes in current package can access it.

In the case of a `final` class, the method's used by other classes in the same package: it's the same as no access modifier (also called "package-private").

Comment: then why not use package-private?

Comment: @Bozho: presumably for historical reasons

Comment: But in use case 2 it would be possible to define the method without visibility qualifier. So maybe it is true that it does not make much sense to have a protected method in a final class.

Comment: @Bozho maybe backward compatibility?

Comment: Maybe the `final` class modifier was added later.

Comment: Since when is package-private not generally used??

Comment: @Pindatjuh, Why do you say that "package-private is not used very much"?

Comment: Now realized that package-private (or package-local) is actually used quite much.

Answer (score 3):

To be used only in its own package

protected - member - Accessible only within its package and its subclasses

if someone defines a method as final then it cannot be Cannot be overridden and dynamically looked up.

Reference here: http://www.javacamp.org/javaI/Modifier.html

Answer (score 1):

The class cannot be further extended or subclassed, but the method is still accessible from within the package.

Answer (score 0):

Just so it's out there:  if this was a class that extended another, the protected method might be extending a protected method in the superclass.  Another possible reason to look for.